# UITableView Cell Does Not Become First Responder When Outside of Current View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `TableViewController` which displays to-do list items. In the controller I have made a button which when pressed creates a new `TableViewCell` at the bottom which has a `UITextView` along with other elements.

Till now this is what I have managed to do -

- Create a new cell upon button tap
- Make the newly created cell's text view first responder

However, from what I have observed everything is working fine except when the last cell in the table is not visible, i.e., it is below the frame. In that case the cell gets created but is not made the first responder or some other cell's text view gets the cursor.

See the output here -
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mRN8MEO5HBJ3ICUiRE0Yc4ib8tp62MYc/view?usp=sharing

Here is the code -

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, InboxCellDelegate {
        
    var cell = InboxCell()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
//         self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
        
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "InboxCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "InboxCell")
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
    }
    
    @IBAction func inboxAddPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        
        addRowToEnd()
        
    }
    
    func addRowToEnd() {
        
        Task.tasks.append("")
        
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: Task.tasks.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
        
        cell.inboxTaskTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
        
    }
    
    func didChangeText(text: String?, cell: InboxCell) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        
        return Task.tasks.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InboxCell", for: indexPath) as! InboxCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.delegate = self
        
        cell.inboxTaskTextView.text = Task.tasks[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
    
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        
        return true
    }
    
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            Task.tasks.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

}
```

I have tried to scroll to the bottom of the table first and then making the newly created cell first responder but that didn't work. In that case only the very first cell created becomes the first responder while the subsequent cells are created but the cursor remains in the very first cell.

Here is the block of code I used for scrolling before `cell.inboxTaskTextView.becomeFirstResponder()` -

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: Task.tasks.count - 1, section: 0)
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
}
```

**Edit -**

After having tried for a while this is the closest I have got to a solution.

After `Task.tasks.append("")` I have added the following code which scrolls down the view to the bottom -

```
if tableView.contentSize.height >= tableView.frame.size.height {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: Task.tasks.count - 1, section: 0)
            self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
        }
}
```

In this case the newly created cell becomes first responder but only momentarily. The keyboard doesn't even appear fully before it gets dismissed automatically in a flash. This happens only for cells that are created below the fold - i.e. when the table view has to scroll down and then create a new cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep it simple first. Put a breakpoint or `print("indexPath.row = \(indexPath.row)")` at the beginning of `cellForRow` UITableViewDataSource method that you implemented already.

Add the new task and see if your cellForRow is being called for the indexPath corresponding to your new cell.

If not - you may have to scroll the tableView up at least 44points or whatever is needed to reach the area where the new cell should already be displayed. If you don't do that - the cell might not be created yet, and `cell` most probably refers to the last cell in the table view (or it could also be referring to a cell in the pool if some logic is not implemented correctly). So the new cell must be in the visible area before making its `UITextField` or `UITextView` become first responder.

If you know that cell is already visible - better to get an reference to it via

```
let index = IndexPath(row: rowForNewCell, section: 0)
let cell = self.table.cellForRow(at: index)
```

Finally call:

```
cell.inboxTaskTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: When printing `indexPath.row` I don't see any output when the current last cell present in the table view is below the fold. Only when I scroll down the print statement appears in the console. So it is clear that I need to scroll to the bottom before making the new cell first responder. However, in that case only the very first cell becomes first responder and when I press the add button after that, new cells are created below but do not become first responder. I can't figure out why is that happening. Also, referencing via local variable doesn't help either. Things are the same either way.

Comment: Another way to look at it is either I am able to get the table view scroll to the bottom or make the newly created cell first responder (if is appears above the fold). For some reason(s) both are not happening together.

Comment: It's not clear to me where exactly you've added this line `let cell = self.table.cellForRow(at: index)`... Should happen after you finished scrolling and the new cell is visible for sure. Then make it first responder.

Comment: I see some unnecessary code, like switching to main thread when you are already on main thread `DispatchQueue.main.async { }`, then `self.tableView.reloadData()`. Also `var cell = InboxCell()` should not be there.

Comment: If you do scrolling animated - it takes a while, and other functionality after that - may not have the effects you expect, because - the cell is still not visible. It's about to scroll and the code you want to execute after, probably already executed but that all irrelevant (if you don't have the cell visible, or even worse, are referencing a previous cell or a cell from the pool [which is invisible])